# env value sometimes returning null in laravel 5.8 in my local environment

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.8

I recently added a value in .env file in my project.

```
HELLO_TOKEN = "ABCDEFGH"
```

I am trying to access this value from somewhere.

```
env('HELLO_TOKEN')
```

But, sometimes it works,but most of the time it returns null.I tried in two diffent ways but in vain.

Trial 1) If I run,
php artisan config:cache ,
My website design gets broken.
Even if I run `php artisan view:clear` and hard reload, the page design doesn't improve.

Trial 2) If I run,

```
php artisan config:cache,
php artisan config:clear,
php artisan cache:clear
```

My website design is ok, but getting env returns null most of the time.

N:B: I am using laravel version 5.8 and working in windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have any calls to `env` outside of configuration files. When the configuration is cached, with `config:cache`, the `.env` file is not loaded, so all calls to `env` will return null.

> "If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function will return `null`."

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Configuration - Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#configuration-caching)

Comment: Now what am I supposed to do to get env value working?

Comment: you don't make calls to `env` outside of configuration files ... everywhere else you use the configuration system

Comment: How can I use the configuration system? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: This is confusing. I use Stripe and need to apply the Strip API key when calling Stripe functions. For another reason I used `artisan config:cache` as I was adjusting config parameters, but that hosed my app, causing my `Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_API_KEY'));` functions to all receive a null instead of the API key and subsequently crash. If I was to follow the keep-everything-in-the config-file approach, how do I then get my Stripe API credentials to where they're needed in code without hard-coding them in place?

Comment: @Hondaman900 you call `env` in the config file and in your code you only make references to the config system, not `env`, as when you cache the config it doesn't load the environmental vars